# Silverlight WCF Service, Object Moved

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application which gets data through a Silverlight WCF Service, and this service was previously functioning.  I made some namespace and assembly name changes to the application, and now whenever I try to access the wcf service, I get the following 302 error in fiddler.

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/5.1 Date: Wed, 30 Sep
>   2009 18:26:52 GMT X-Powered-By:
>   ASP.NET X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
>   Location:
>   /PayrollViewFlow/Service/(S(axlnnazmux31bt55famtfvab))/PayrollDataService.svc
>   Cache-Control: private Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 202

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fPayrollViewFlow%2fService%2f(S(axlnnazmux31bt55famtfvab))%2fPayrollDataService.svc">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

The Location and the moved to location seem to be the same.  Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you did not make the namespace change in all places, such that there is now an inconsistency. Places to check are:

- the svc file
- the generated proxy
- config files
- WCF contract

You can allways do a search for the old namespace and see if it is still used

Comment: I tried doing this and everything seemed fine.  I reverted to a previous version and redid all my renaming and there was no problems.  It must have been something that wasn't configured right.

Comment: SoapUI is a great testing tool